# ES function_score min_score for each function

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have in ElasticSearch query like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "boost": "5",
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "test": "bar"
            }
          },
          "random_score": {},
          "weight": 23
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "test": "foo"
            }
          },
          "weight": 42
        }
      ],
      "max_boost": 42,
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "multiply",
      "min_score": 42
    }
  }
}
```

is it possible to set min_score for result from each function ?
I would like to set 2 min_scores, one for bar second for foo.

Comment: What do you mean by `set 2 min_score`? Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean that if it is possible to get score from first score function, check min, and for another score function use another min. Probably not as scoring is done via multiply etc..

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean...can you try and give an example of what you mean? how do you want the scores to be combined?